# Remove selected option from dropdown php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a scenario that I have user's edit profile page in which there is a 'Speciality' dropdown and it's option's are getting fetched through While Loop from database table 'speciality'.
What I want is to show the Selected option at first in dropdown,
for that I have putted following code at top:

```
<option value=""><?php echo $row2["speciality"];?></option>
```

But problem is again while loop is fetching the same option from the database, so it's getting duplicate, and What I want is to remove selected option from while loop's selected options.

Can Any One help?

Full Code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id = $id");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM surgery_team WHERE p_id = $id");
$rows2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
while($patient = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $speciality = $patient['speciality'];   
}
}
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                                FROM speciality 
                                WHERE id = $speciality");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
?>    


<div class="col-6">
    <label class="control-label">Speciality</label>
    <select name="speciality" class="form-control" id="category-dropdown">
    <option value=""><?php echo $row2["speciality"];?></option>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                            FROM speciality 
                            WHERE parent_id = 0");
                    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <option value=""><?php echo $row["speciality"];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: How come you start using `$row2` and then the full code is using `$row` are you talking about the same or different code here

Comment: I dont think you are showing us enough code. I have an idea what you really want to do is set the `selected="selected"` attribute for the option that the user has selected previously. But I cannot be sure without seeing more code

Comment: @RiggsFolly Added full code

Comment: Cant be, there is no connection being made and to many `}`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for advice but can you help me to skip the selected option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of throwing 2 copies to the list, just make the one selected the selected item of the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-6">
    <label class="control-label">Speciality</label>
    <select name="speciality" class="form-control" id="category-dropdown">
    
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                            FROM speciality 
                            WHERE parent_id = 0");
                    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $attr = $row2["speciality"] == $row["speciality"] ? "selected='selected'" : '';

    echo "<option $attr value='$row[speciality]'>$row[speciality]</option>";
}
```

Comment: I used two copied because firstly user's speciality id is getting fetched from 'patient' table and using that same id I am fetching speciality column's name which is stored in another table i.e: speciality.